# Collect All appID's from a JSON file

Tags: json, vb.net

My question is about a JSON file, of which I'm getting errors when putting certain values in a text component.

```
{
"response": {
    "game_count": 4,
    "games": [
        {
            "appid": 10,
            "playtime_forever": 0
        },
        {
            "appid": 20,
            "playtime_forever": 0
        },
        {
            "appid": 30,
            "playtime_forever": 0
        },
        {
            "appid": 40,
            "playtime_forever": 0
        }
    ]

   }
}
```

I'm trying to get the values "10,20,30,40" from "appid" in a RichTextBox, one below the other. For this, I am using this code:

```
JsonString = file

        Dim jsonObject As JObject = JObject.Parse(JsonString)
        Dim JsonArray As JArray = JArray.Parse(jsonObject.SelectToken("games").ToString)
        For Each item As JObject In JsonArray
            RichTextBox2.Text = item.SelectToken("appid").ToString

        Next
```

But I'm getting the following error in line 4 of the above code:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object

Is there a way to fix this? I believe my code is right. I'm using the NewtonSoft library.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Why do you think you need to parse it twice?  Please read [ask] and take the [tour]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`SelectTokens("..appid")`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenJsonPath.htm) to recursively descent the JSON token hierarchy and find values of properties named `"appid"`, where `".."` is the [JSONPath](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) *recursive descent operator*:

```
Dim jsonObject As JToken = JToken.Parse(JsonString)
Dim appids = jsonObject _ 
    .SelectTokens("..appid") _
    .Select(Function(t) CType(t, Long)) _
    .ToList()
```

After finding all `"appid"` values I cast then to `Long` using an [explicit conversion cast](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_op_Explicit_3.htm).  You could cast to `Int` If you are certain that all `appid` values will be less than `Int.MaxValue`.  Or you could cast then to `String` if you're not interested in the numeric values.

Working [.Net fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zVIIFk).

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to use your code to improve my studies :D